# WHM configuration editor for php.ini

Tags: whm

i am trying to edit php.ini in whm configuration editor , so i went to advance tab and edited and saved but i dont know after saving its showing your php.ini file has been saved but the page its showing is blank so its not affecting my php.ini.
i wanted to change  post_max_size=512m 
and     memory_limit=512m
Anybody knows why its not saving .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a master WHM or just a reseller account, if it is just a reseller account you may not be able to change the php.ini - generally in this case you would make changes via the .htaccess file for each site, or place a php.ini in the site directory where you wanted the changes to apply.

If it is the master server account you can alternatively edit the php.ini located in /usr/local/lib/php.ini via ssh then restart httpd which will update it.

Comment: I've placed the php.ini in the site directory with the changes I want, but it doesn't seem to have had any effect. Do you know what might be wrong? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In WHM - Tweak Settings - Tab = PHP then cPanel PHP max upload size (maximum: 2,047)